# Which block file calls for My Account page when it loads

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, customer-account, phtml

I have written some helper functions, which does some database inserts
The problem is I am calling all these functions from my `phtml` which gets loaded first time when `My account` is loaded for the first time.

Due to this, the changes on databases doesn't reflect on the first go, when I reload my page again then I see those changes.

There must be some block file which loads before `My account` phtml file so that I can call my helper function from that block file.

Where can I find those block files/ controller files of `My Account` and how can i call my helper function from those

Right now i am calling my helper function from my phtml like this:-

```
$temp_block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('YX\Catalog\Block\OrderHelper');
```

$customerHelper = $this->helper('YX\Customer\Helper\CustomerHelper');

```
 if (!($customerHelper->isCustomer())){
     $customerID = $customerHelper->getCustomerId();
     $orderId = $customerHelper->getOrderId();
     $temp_block->guestToCustomer($orderId,$customerID);

 }
```

I am converting my guest checkout orders to my account order, When the user places an order as guest on success page he/she is asked to sign up to make an account, on signing up, the user is taken to my account page, so all the logic I wrote in phtml file in recent.phtml which is the first page so I wrote the above code in my recent.phtml , but it doesn't get reflected on the first go as the file is already been loaded, on the second reload I get to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the dashboard page, Then please open on the layout filed

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml 
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml
```

Here Magento mention, it is a list of file which is loaded for the customer dashboard page.

Also, I don't understand, what you have tried to achieve. But on the fly update customer data and get that data update on the same execution is not a good idea.

And PHP is server-side language, So the content of the page is not updated yet until next execution of the same page. So suggest to update content using AJAX and  Implement the private content.

Comment: well hi Amit, I am converting my guest checkout orders to my account order, When the user places an order as guest on success page he/she is asked to sign up to make an account, on signing up, the user is taken to my account page, so all the logic I wrote in phtml file in recent.phtml which is the first page so i wrote the above code in my recent.phtml , but it doesnt get reflected on the first go as the file is already been loaded, on the second reload I get to see the changes

Comment: Why you don't use any event like customer login. Do the logic like, on customer login update customer data with guest order that is best a feasible solution.OR use Cronjob for update  order with customer

Comment: Thats why i am thinking it to call those helper functions from block files of My account before any of the phtml loads

Comment: Can you guide me through events or cron job thing, are you talking about javascript events on customer sign up

Comment: Hey, once the customer is signed up write an observer for this event customer_register_success and get this order to this customer placed.